# Asymptotics of the integral of an oscillating function

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I would like to know the asymptotics of the following sequences of integrals:
$$ I_n = \displaystyle { \int _0 ^{+ \infty}
                              \dfrac{t^n}{(t + i)^{n + 1}}
                              \cdot
                              e^{-t}
                              \ dt
                       }
$$

Using a deformation of path with Cauchy theorem, I've shown that
$$ I_n = \displaystyle { \int _{i \mathbb{R}^+}
                              \dfrac{t^n}{(t + i)^{n + 1}}
                              \cdot
                              e^{-t}
                              \ dt
                         =
                         \int _0 ^{+ \infty}
                              \dfrac{t^n}{(t + 1)^{n + 1}}
                              \cdot
                              e^{-it}
                              \ dt
                       }
$$

I therefore have tried using Laplace method, but I have been unable to conclude anything...

Moreover, I didn't manage to use computer software to have some reliable numeric values, because of the oscilating function $t \mapsto e^{-it}$. So, I haven't got any conjecture...

Answer (score 3):

The saddle point $t^\ast$ is obtained by solving $f'(t)=0$ for $f(t)=-t+n\ln t-(n+1)\ln(t+i)$, for large $n$ we find $f(t^\ast)=-2\sqrt{in}$, so we arrive at the approximation for the integral $I_n\approx\exp(-2\sqrt{in})$.

The plot compares exact (gold) and approximate (blue) absolute values for $n$ up to 200 (multiply horizontal axis labels by 10).

[image]

Comment: Nice cart, to confirm theory!
I find two possibilities to the saddle point $t^\star$: $\dfrac{-1 - i \pm \sqrt{2i (2n + 1)}}{2}$. Which one should we consider?

Comment: Do you have a link on with theory and example on Laplace method? I thought it applies on integral $\displaystyle { \int _a ^b g(t) e^{-\lambda f(t)} \ dt } $, with a function $f$ non-depending on the variable $\lambda$?

Comment: It looks to me that the picture shows divergence of the blue and gold plots.

Comment: Using the saddle node $\dfrac{-1 -i + \sqrt{2i(2n + 1)}}{2}$, I conjecture that
$ I_n
   \underset{n \longrightarrow + \infty}{\sim}
   \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{n^{\frac{1}{4}}} e^{i \big ( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi}{8} \big )} e^{-2 \sqrt{i n}}
$.
This has been confirmed by numerical result for $n = 2^k$ for $k \in [\![0;14]\!]$